# discord js returning empty array when running bot.guilds.cache.array()

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

Hello I am making a discord bot and im trying to get a list of every guild its in.
To do this I am running `bot.guilds.cache.array()` to try to get an array of the guilds its in.
But when I do this I get an empty array.

```js
const discord = require("discord.js")
const bot = new discord.Client()
bot.on("ready", x=> {
    bot.guilds.fetch()
    bot.channels.fetch()
})
console.log(bot.guilds.cache.array())
bot.login("y4932y14ui23ndsabmkcbaskjb485432534") // not my actual token lol
```

The code above me logs [], an empty array. And of course that is not my actual bot token.

Answer (score 1):

First, don’t leak your bot token, especially on a public site.  Use another file and import it so sharing your code won’t possibly go horribly wrong.

Second, you want to keep as many functions as possible within your event listeners, so you should move this into the `ready` event listener.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(bot.guilds.cache.array().map(guild => guild.name)
})
```

Note: `.map()` is optional here, but assuming you want this to be more readable and just a list of guild names instead of objects to perform functions upon, it helps in this scenario.

Edit: Fixed bug after personally testing

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this out. And also I did not put my actual token in, I just spammed random characters, thanks for the warning though.